# CPP example clarification

Tags: canada, retirement

Can someone explain https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/payroll/payroll-deductions-contributions/canada-pension-plan-cpp/cpp-contribution-rates-maximums-exemptions.html  with a simple example?

Does it mean that someone making 100K/annum still has maximum pensionable earnings of $58700 and can contribute up to $5796 to the CPP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you earn $100k you will pay 5.25% of your income into the CPP plan until you earn $58700 and then you will stop paying.  So around Aug. you will have no more CPP (or EI) deductions.  Your employer will also have to pay this amount.  $5796 is the sum of both portions.

5.25% isn't exactly right since the first $3500 is exempt.

If you work at least 83% of the time between 18 and 65 earning the YMPE or more, you will get a maximum pension of 25% of the YMPE.  It's a bit less since it's based on the 5 yr YMPE avg. It's ~$14k this year.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on "5.25% isn't exactly right since the first $3500 is exempt."? Is this a mandatory contribution? What if I don't work for 83% of the time?

Comment: You pay 5.25% on earnings up to $58700 excluding the first $3500, so the max is $55200 *5.25% = $2898.  It's mandatory.  If you work less in time or money then you get proportionately less.

Comment: So I suppose CPP is one certain source of retirement income apart from RRSP and TFSA which are voluntary, right? Is CPP the equivalent of social security in the USA?

Comment: CPP is similar to US SS in that you pay in and the govt saves it and then pays it back.  Canada also has OAS which is ~$6k per year and is paid from general revenue.

Comment: OK. So when retires, one gets CPP + OAS (~20K) for sure, and RRSP and TFSA if one has contributed to them before, right?

Comment: OAS has residency requirements of 10 yrs minimum but there are bi-lateral residence agreements with some other countries.  Even without that there is GIS or essentially welfare for seniors of up to ~ $11k.